# Koala compiler not working in windows

Tags: less, koala

I need to compile LESS to CSS file. i installed the koala GUI application in my windows7 PC. but not able to see the app window when i clicked open the Koala app. But Koala.exe is there in my task manager's process tab. Please help me in this . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer from GITHUB that before i had version 1.4.0 that is having some issue in windows. so I installed the latest version 1.4.1, there it is working good.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the terminal feature of Aptana 3 and native lessc. I installed node, then I installed less with `npm install -g less` then I used the terminal in Aptana with `lessc -ru style.less > style.css`. It worked properly:)

Answer (score 0):

If the Koala exe is in the process list or even if the koala notification process is shown in the task manager, kill these. Kill anything related to Koala compiler and restart the app. It happened to me and this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below to fix the issue

**1.** Open system tray(by clicking up-arrow from the bottom right) and click koala

**2.** Go to settings, by clicking on the settings button(available in left sidebar)

**3.** Go to "General" settings

**4.** Uncheck the option "Minimize To Tray"

**5.** Click 'Okay' button

That's it, the issue will get fixed